# c- Error when assigning structure member in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, member

I am writing a program in C to find the shift in a ceaser cipher.

As part of this I first perform every possible shift, 0-26, on the message to decipher, I use a struct to store the shift and the message. To do this I have passed a structure to a function as a pointer. However, when I try to change the message member of the struct to the deciphered message I get the error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int') on the line 'strcpy(s->message, cipherText);'.

In the function I also assign a local variable to a structure member and this works fine.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ENCRYPT 0
#define DECRYPT 1

struct Solution {
    int key;
    char message[];
};

void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode);

void main(){
    struct Solution solutions[26];
    char cipherText[] = "lipps, asvph.";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i) {
        solutions[i].key = i;
        Ceaser(&solutions[i], cipherText, DECRYPT);
        printf("Key: %d\tPlain text: %s\n", solutions[i].key, 
        solutions[i].message);
    }
}

void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode) {

    int len = strlen(cipherText);
    int c;
    int key = s->key;

    for (int s = 0; s <= 26; ++s) {
        if (mode == DECRYPT) {
            key *= -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            c = cipherText[i];

            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                cipherText[i] = 'A' + ((c + key - 'A') % 26);           
            } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                cipherText[i] = 'a' + ((c + key - 'a') % 26);           
            }
        }
    //Error occurs below
    strcpy(s->message, cipherText);
    }
}
```

Comment: `s->message` : `char message[];` doesn't have spaces.

Comment: The problem is that you have two variables named s. The inner int s shadows the outer Solution *s. If you use gcc, the -Wshadow flag is nifty to locate issues like this one.

Comment: @BjornA. Thanks I though it would be something simple I can't believe I didn't notice the conflict. Thanks for the compiler tip too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing the `for(int s=...` correctly and the compiler thinks that by `s->` you are referring to the loop variable `s` instead of the `Solution* s` function parameter.

That is why you get that *invalid type* error.

The following is a fixed (and better indented) version:

```
void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode) {
  int len = strlen(cipherText);
  int c;
  int key = s->key;

  for (int s = 0; s <= 26; ++s) {
    if (mode == DECRYPT) {
      key *= -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      c = cipherText[i];

      if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        cipherText[i] = 'A' + ((c + key - 'A') % 26);
      } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        cipherText[i] = 'a' + ((c + key - 'a') % 26);
      }
    }
  } //<--------was missing 

  strcpy(s->message, cipherText);
}
```

If you let the compiler warning `-Wshadow` works what you get is very informative.

```
g++
test.cpp:65:30: note: shadowed declaration is here
 void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode) {

clang++
note: previous declaration is here
void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode) {


icpc
warning #1599: declaration hides parameter "s" (declared at line 65)
    for (int s = 0; s <= 26; ++s) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Ceaser(struct Solution *s, char cipherText[], int mode){
....
for (int s = 0; s <= 26; ++s){
```

Can you not see the obvious conflict here - you are using the same variable name twice. The `int s` will override the previous declaration of `s` for the scope of the for loop so your code won't be able to interact with the one declared previously.

Change the first `s` into a proper variable name (ie "solution") so that you avoid the conflict and also is obvious what the purpose of the variable is. Single character variables aren't very clear what they're for, even if they're just used in for loops.